# anchor tag in wechat mini programs wxml

Tags: javascript, anchor, wechat, wechat-miniprogram, weixinjsbridge

How to use anchor tags in wxml?

I have a variable in which I am setting a URL.
I need to display something like "Click here" in the view and make the user click the URL.

The URL is not any other domain but something within the weixin so that shouldn't be a problem I guess. This does not make the click here appear as a link.

```
<view class="container log-list">
 <block>
      <a href = '#'><text class="userinfo-nickname" bindLoad="onLoad">click here</text></a>
    </block>
</view>
```

Comment: could you explain more about the "anchor tag"?

Comment: I want to add a link to my mini program and hence trying to add it using <a> tag like usual. But it seems not to work.

Comment: If you want to link to the common webpage,you could use the "web-view" components.

Comment: I am aware of the web-view components. But my use case is like I want a link to be present and when user clicks the link, I am redirecting the user to another mini program by navigateToMiniProgram.

Comment: If you want to link to other miniprogram pages.it needs to bind event for the tag and then write code to navigate to other page. try "wx.navigateTo({url:'/pages/xxxx'})"

Comment: Also, can I use iframe here and load a mini program within another Mini Program?

Comment: it hasn't iframe components...

Comment: Is the aim page writing from you?

Comment: Is the aim page writing from you?  - I did not get you there, pardon me

Comment: i don't kown you want to navigate to the aim page cate.If it's common web page with doname,web-view is only method of showing it.If it's wxminiprogram page,you can only use navigate functions of wx-miniprogram.

Comment: The web-view is similar as the iframe tag in common webpage

Comment: Got it, thanks. Does mini program wxml not support iframe at all?

Comment: yes,it has not iframe.Before using web-view,don't forget config the white doname in wx-miniprogram admin.If not, pages won't show instead of a white page in production environment

Comment: Where to configure the domain name whitelist? @taolu

Comment: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/?lang=en_US